# Is okHttp library thread-safe for webSocket?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm using okHttp library to manage my webSocket connection. so my problem is that I'm not sure if okHttp is thread safe or not.

I mean does it throw exception if sending some data and in the same time server application send data to my client application and okHttp should receive that data?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Concurrency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OkHttp’s websockets are safe for concurrent use. You can have multiple threads calling send() concurrently and also concurrently receive responses in the callback.